# Запрос по двум условиям MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Имею 3 таблицы:

**Values**

id - products_id - properties_id - value

**Properties**

id - name

1. Размер
2. Цвет
3. Новинка

**Products**

id - name - category - price

Необходимо вывести все товары зелёного цвета и являющиеся новинкой.

Смог сделать запрос к одному пункту

```
 - R::getAll('SELECT products.* FROM products  JOIN `values` as `v` ON
   v.products_id = products.id JOIN `properties` as `pr` ON pr.id =
   v.properties_id WHERE pr.name = "Новинка" AND v.value = "1"');
```

по 2м не понимаю как сделать запрос, пробовал через GROUP BY - выдаёт ошибку, INTERSECT вроде как тоже оказался не уместен
Проблема в том, что нужно вывести не дублируя, тоесть чтобы осталось например

-1 велосипед

//он является и новинкой и зелёный,
а не

-1 велосипед

//новинка)

-2 велосипед

(зелёный)

Comment: Есть мысль, что возможно нужно использовать "Вложенные запросы", но пока я не разобрался, как его написать в данном случае. По идее нужно написать отбор по Цвет = зелёный, а потом из получившегося вывести то, что ещё и Новинка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут стоит подумать на тему "А действительно ли нужно присоединять таблицу *properties*?" Насколько я понял, таблица *properties* является справочником, а результирующий запрос должен выдать товары по выставленному фильтру, используя параметры вызова из справочника. Т.е. SQL-запрос выполняется как результат HTTP-запроса со страницы. Значит, параметр id для названия свойства из таблицы *properties* можно получить прямо со страницы и передать в виде параметров HTTP-запроса - `[2 => "Зеленый", 3 => "1"]`, чтобы не заморачиваться с поиском по названию свойства. Тогда задача существенно упрощается: нужно отобрать товары из *products*, используя всего 2 таблицы - собственно *products* и описание его свойств *values*.

Запрос для такого действия может выглядеть либо как его сделал @АлександрНиколаев (с "разворачиванием" имеющихся свойств в выборку через LEFT JOIN):

```sql
SELECT prod.* FROM products AS prod
LEFT JOIN 'values' AS val_color ON val_color.products_id = prod.id
LEFT JOIN 'values' AS val_new ON val_new.products_id = prod.id
WHERE 
   val_new.properties_id=3 AND val_new.value="1" AND
   val_color.properties_id=2 AND val_color.value="Зеленый"
```

либо с выбором ID подходящих строк из *products* с помощью вложенного запроса (я специально привожу более сложный пример запроса, использующий `GROUP BY` и "разворачивание" свойств *properties* через `GROUP_CONCAT()` как пример возможной альтернативы):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `id` IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT `products_id`
   FROM `values` 
   WHERE 
     (`properties_id`=2 AND `value`="Зеленый") OR
     (`properties_id`=3 AND `value`="1")
   GROUP BY `products_id` 
   HAVING 
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `properties_id` ORDER BY `properties_id` SEPARATOR ",")="2,3");
```

Если же значение критерия нужно искать именно по названию критерия (т.е. `["Цвет" => "Зеленый", "Новинка" => "1"]`), то вложенный запрос существенно "потяжелеет".

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `id` IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT v.`products_id`
   FROM `values` AS v LEFT JOIN `properties` AS p ON v.`properties_id`=p.`id`
   WHERE 
     (p.`name`="Цвет" AND v.`value`="Зеленый") OR
     (p.`name`="Новинка" AND v.`value`="1")
   GROUP BY v.`products_id` 
   HAVING 
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.`name` ORDER BY p.`name` SEPARATOR ",")="Новинка,Цвет");
```

Тестовый пример:

```
MariaDB [homestead]> select * from properties;
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Размер         |
|  2 | Цвет           |
|  3 | Новинка        |
+----+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [homestead]> select * from products;
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
| id | name               | category | price |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Велосипед          | 5        |   100 |
|  2 | Велосипед          | 5        |   200 |
|  3 | Самокат            | 7        |   150 |
|  4 | Велосипед          | 5        |   100 |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [homestead]> select * from `values`;
+----+------------+---------------+----------------+
| id | product_id | properties_id | value          |
+----+------------+---------------+----------------+
|  1 |          1 |             2 | Синий          |
|  2 |          1 |             3 | 1              |
|  3 |          2 |             3 | 1              |
|  4 |          2 |             2 | Зеленый        |
|  5 |          2 |             1 | King Size      |
|  6 |          3 |             2 | Зеленый        |
|  7 |          4 |             2 | Синий          |
|  8 |          4 |             3 | 1              |
+----+------------+---------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [homestead]> SELECT prod.* FROM products AS prod LEFT JOIN `values` AS val_color ON val_color.products_id=prod.id LEFT JOIN `values` AS val_new ON val_new.products_id=prod.id WHERE val_new.properties_id=3 AND val_new.value="1" AND val_color.properties_id=2 AND val_color.value="Зеленый";
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
| id | name               | category | price |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
|  2 | Велосипед          | 5        |   200 |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [homestead]> SELECT * FROM `products`  WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `products_id` FROM `values` WHERE (`properties_id`=2 AND `value`="Зеленый") OR      (`properties_id`=3 AND `value`="1") GROUP BY `products_id` HAVING       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `properties_id` ORDER BY `properties_id` SEPARATOR ",")="2,3");
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
| id | name               | category | price |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
|  2 | Велосипед          | 5        |   200 |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [homestead]> SELECT * FROM `products`  WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT v.`products_id` FROM `values` AS v LEFT JOIN `properties` AS p ON v.`properties_id`=p.`id` WHERE (p.`name`="Цвет" AND v.`value`="Зеленый") OR      (p.`name`="Новинка" AND v.`value`="1") GROUP BY v.`products_id` HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.`name` ORDER BY p.`name` SEPARATOR ",")="Новинка,Цвет");
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
| id | name               | category | price |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
|  2 | Велосипед          | 5        |   200 |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Я не силён в MySQL - подскажите, почему вы используете и GROUP_CONCAT и DISTINCT? они же выполняют +- одно и то-же, отбрасывают дубли?
P/S: пытаюсь воспроизвести ваш вариант, пока не работает, пытаюсь править.

Comment: Вариант @АлександрНиколаев работает. Я всего лишь убрал избыточный JOIN в нем и добавил проверку значения признака "Новый", поскольку не знаю, как Вы будете его менять в дальнейшем - удалением записи из _values_ или изменением значения в той же таблице. В моем же варианте GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...) обеспечивает отсутствие дубликатов в результате GROUP_CONCAT(). Уберите отсюда DISTINCT, добавьте запись-дубликат с цветом в _properties_ - и Вы увидите. Но Вы правы, запросы можно упростить. Сейчас откорректирую.

Comment: Слегка упростил запросы с помощью GROUP_CONCAT(). Проверил все 3 запроса на работоспособность - все работают. А у Вас запросы работают? Если нет - то какой запрос какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: ``$sample = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT v.`products_id`
   FROM `values` AS v LEFT JOIN `properties` AS p ON v.`properties_id`=p.`id`
   WHERE 
     (p.`name`="Цвет" AND `value`="GREEN") OR
     (p.`name`="Новинка" AND `value`="1")
   GROUP BY v.`products_id` 
   HAVING 
     FIND_IN_SET("Новинка", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.`name` SEPARATOR ","))!=0 AND
     FIND_IN_SET("Цвет", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.`name` SEPARATOR ","))!=0');
``
Такой запрос выдаёт ошибку о синтаксисе, как в VSC так и в PHPMyAdmin

Comment: ``R::getAll('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM products 
JOIN `values` as `v` ON v.products_id = products.id 
JOIN `properties` as `pr` ON pr.id = v.properties_id 
WHERE pr.name = "Новинка" AND v.value = "1") 
WHERE pr.name = "GREEN" AND v.value = "3" GROUP BY products_id');  ``
Нельзя ли что-то подобное сделать? только рабочее, смысл в том, чтобы сделать выборку, а потом выборку из выборки) ну сначал получить все записи с "новинка" а из них выбрать те, что " зелёный"? или так нельзя писать? я просто совсем новичок ещё, но хочется как-то логично написать

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов если выдает ошибку - значит что-то не так. Но для того, чтобы определить, что именно не так, надо как минимум прочитать сообщение об ошибке. А его-то Вы и не приводите. Так что мой ответ - "Либо что-то случилось, либо одно из двух." Тем более, что Вы используете более старый вариант запроса, и к тому же покореженный... Ну ладно, ладно. Уговорили. Вангую. ГДЕ ЗАКРЫВАЮЩАЯ СКОБКА В ПОДЗАПРОСЕ? P.S. Копипастить тоже нужно правильно. :)

Comment: Наконец-таки всё работает! Спасибо большое, правда мне не очень понятно назначение SEPARATOR здесь. Но я разберусь потихоньку. Пока разбирал этот вопрос узнал о sql больше чем знал до этого)

Comment: может вы можете тогда подсказать, как мне вытащить одновременно имя, размер и цвет? а то у меня получается (пользуясь запросом через LEFT JOIN ы, так как он проще для меня) отобразить все товары зелёного цвета, являющиеся новинками, но вот в values у меня получается только размер, как получить ещё и Цвет теперь?

Comment: использую этот запрос 
        ``$join = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM products 
        LEFT JOIN `values` AS color ON color.products_id = products.id 
        LEFT JOIN `values` AS new ON new.products_id = products.id 
        LEFT JOIN `values` AS size ON size.products_id = products.id
        JOIN properties AS p 
        WHERE 
        new.properties_id = 3 AND new.value = 1
         AND 
        color.properties_id = 2 AND color.value = "GREEN"
        AND
        size.properties_id = 1
        GROUP BY size.products_id');  
          var_dump ($join);``

Comment: Чет не понял вопроса. "_у меня получается ... отобразить все товары зелёного цвета, являющиеся новинками, но вот в values у меня получается только размер, как получить ещё и Цвет теперь?_" - так он же задан - _Зеленый_! 8[]

Comment: Я имел ввиду, как сделать выборку так, чтобы он отобразил и цвет и размер и имя товара, одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

```
select prod.* from products as prod
left join values as val_color on val_color.products_id = prod.id
left join values as val_new on val_new.products_id = prod.id
left join properties as prop on prop.id = val_color.properties_id and prop.id = val_new.properties_id
where val_new.properties_id = 3 and val_color.properties_id = 2 and val_color.value = "Зеленый"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако этот вариант выдаёт пустой массив, скорее всего изза того, что строки val_new.properties_id = 3 and val_color.properties_id = 2 - взаимоисключающие, ведь нет строки у которой id =2 и 3 одновременно.

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов вы наверное не заметили что они относятся к разным left join и не как не являются взаимоисключающими

Comment: Этим запросом мы выводим строки products, в связях с которыми один values с properties_id = 3, а второй values с properties_id = 2 и value = "Зеленый"

Comment: **left join properties as prop on prop.id = val_color.properties_id and prop.id = val_new.properties_id** - взаимоисключающее условие, поскольку если **(prop.id = val_color.properties_id) === 2** (код "Цвета"), то он никак не может быть **(prop.id = val_new.properties_id) === 3** (код "Новинка"). :(

Comment: Если бы можно было развязаться от _properties_, т.е. условия поиска преобразовать из **["Цвет" => "Зеленый", "Новинка" => "1"]** в **[2 => "Зеленый", 3 => "1"]**, т.е. искать не по _properties.name_, а сразу по _values.properties_id_ то запрос 
**select prod.* from products as prod
left join values as val_color on val_color.products_id = prod.id
left join values as val_new on val_new.products_id = prod.id
where val_new.properties_id=3 and val_new.values="1" and val_color.properties_id=2 and val_color.value="Зеленый"** был бы оптимальным.

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko да ладно, вот вам даже видео записал, не поленился https://youtu.be/AYaewqoVh2k

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев, да ладно Вам. Разве я сказал, что запрос не работает? Поменяйте в запросе "prod.*" на "*" - сразу увидите, о чем я. :) Ну а поскольку из таблицы _properties_ ни в select, ни в where ничего не используется, то от удаления "left join properties as prop on prop.id = val_color.properties_id and prop.id = val_new.properties_id" запрос только выиграет. Я именно об этом.

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko запрос возможно и выигрывает, но возможен запрос с параметрами, которых нет в таблице properties. Это своего рода проверка.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев, если Вы меняли в запросе "prop.*" на "*", то должны были убедиться, что в результирующей выборке поля prop.id и prop.name ВСЕГДА равны NULL. Поскольку prop.id не может быть одновременно равным и 3, и 2. Видимо, Вы изначально строили более сложный запрос, потом его упростили, а этот кусок - рудимент, который не удалили. На результат выборки он не влияет, только на скорость и сложность. Согласитесь уже с этим и давайте закроем тему.